# Python: Plot all categorical subset combinations in one figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, automation

I want to generate plots showing how a rate changes, on average, across time for various groups and subgroups.  I'm able to do it by hand, creating each grouping, defining each y-value set, and calling each plot manually.  The trouble is, doing this for all combinations of groups/subgroups is impractical.  Yet I'm not sure how to generalize the procedure.

My data has a `year`, several categorical variables, and a numeric `rate`.  It looks something like this, although in reality there are many more categorical variables:

```
df.head()
Out [33]:
   year gender   race state  rate
0  2015      F  White    AL  0.01
1  2013      F  White    NC  0.48
2  2013      F  White    IN  0.07
3  2013      M  White    NJ  0.95
4  2013      F  White    NY  0.09
```

I want to overlay the various groups and subgroups:

[image: how group averages change over time]

Is there a more elegant way of subsetting/automating the generation of this/these plots?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raw_data = {'year' : [2015 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2014 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2017 , 2013 , 2016 , 2017 , 2016 , 2015 , 2014 , 2014 , 2013 , 2013 , 2017 , 2014 , 2013 , 2016 , 2014 , 2016 , 2015 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2013 , 2017 , 2015 , 2015 , 2013 , 2013 , 2014]

, 'gender' : ['F' , 'F' , 'F' , 'M' , 'F' , 'F' , 'F' , 'M' , 'F' , 'M' , 'F' , 'M' , 'F' , 'M' , 'M' , 'M' , 'M' , 'M' , 'M' , 'M' , 'F' , 'M' , 'F' , 'M' , 'M' , 'M' , 'F' , 'M' , 'F' , 'F' , 'F' , 'M' , 'F' , 'M' , 'F' , 'F' , 'F' , 'F' , 'M' , 'M' , 'M' , 'F' , 'M' , 'M' , 'F' , 'M' , 'F' , 'M' , 'F']

, 'race' : ['White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'Black' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'Black' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'Hispanic' , 'White' , 'Multiple' , 'White' , 'White' , 'Black' , 'Asian/Hawaii/PI' , 'Asian/Hawaii/PI' , 'Black' , 'Black' , 'Black' , 'Hispanic' , 'Black' , 'Black' , 'Black' , 'Black' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'White' , 'Black' , 'Multiple' , 'White' , 'White' , 'Black']

, 'state' : ['AL' , 'NC' , 'IN' , 'NJ' , 'NY' , 'NY' , 'NY' , 'ME' , 'MD' , 'NC' , 'NC' , 'NC' , 'AL' , 'IN' , 'MD' , 'MD' , 'ME' , 'IN' , 'AL' , 'NC' , 'IN' , 'NJ' , 'NY' , 'AL' , 'IN' , 'MD' , 'MD' , 'ME' , 'IN' , 'AL' , 'NC' , 'IN' , 'NJ' , 'ME' , 'MD' , 'NC' , 'NC' , 'NC' , 'AL' , 'IN' , 'MD' , 'ME' , 'MD' , 'NC' , 'NC' , 'NC' , 'AL' , 'IN' , 'MD']

, 'rate' : [0.01 , 0.48 , 0.07 , 0.95 , 0.09 , 0.09 , 0.08 , 0.89 , 0.55 , 0.38 , 0.23 , 0.66 , 0.46 , 0.24 , 0.07 , 0.75 , 0.67 , 0.60 , 0.36 , 0.18 , 0.56 , 0.27 , 0.98 , 0.89 , 0.17 , 0.72 , 0.23 , 0.10 , 0.81 , 0.04 , 0.41 , 0.16 , 0.39 , 0.12 , 0.95 , 0.99 , 0.16 , 0.52 , 0.74 , 0.31 , 0.36 , 0.16 , 0.02 , 0.22 , 0.33 , 0.30 , 0.90 , 0.14 , 0.16]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns= ['year', 'gender', 'race', 'state', 'rate'])

gb_overall = df.groupby(['year'])['rate'].mean()
gb_gender = df.groupby(['year', 'gender'])['rate'].mean()
gb_gender_race = df.groupby(['year', 'gender', 'race'])['rate'].mean()

x = gb_overall.index

y_overall = gb_overall.values
y_f = gb_gender.xs('F', level=1)
y_m = gb_gender.xs('M', level=1)
y_f_r = gb_gender_race.xs(('F', 'White'), level=['gender', 'race'])

fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.plot(x, y_overall, marker = 'o')
plt.plot(x, y_f, marker = 'o')
plt.plot(x, y_m, marker = 'o')
plt.plot(x, y_f_r, marker = 'o')

axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim(left=2012.5)
axes.set_title('Year vs. Average Rate', fontsize= 24)
axes.set_xlabel('Year', fontsize= 16)
axes.set_ylabel('Average Rate', fontsize= 16)
axes.legend(['Overall', 'F', 'M', 'White F'], fontsize=14, loc= 'best', frameon= True, edgecolor= 'black')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to build a single dataframe shaped and organized for using pandas plot.

```
white_f = gb_gender_race.xs(('F','White'), level=['gender','race']).rename('White F')
gender = gb_gender.unstack()
overall = gb_overall.rename('Overall')
df_chart = pd.concat([white_f, gender, overall], axis=1)
axes = df_chart.plot(marker = 'o')
axes.set_xlim(left=2012.5)
axes.set_title('Year vs. Average Rate', fontsize= 24)
axes.set_xlabel('Year', fontsize= 16)
axes.set_ylabel('Average Rate', fontsize= 16)
axes.legend(['Overall', 'F', 'M', 'White F'], fontsize=14, loc= 'best', frameon= True, edgecolor= 'black')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary, you can semi-automate plotting with various conditions. I omitted graph-styling part of your code to focus on the essentials.

```
# overall plot
df.groupby('year').rate.mean().plot(label='Overall', marker='o')

# a dictionary to store various labels(keys) and conditions(values).
# by editing/adding conditions, you can customise your plots.
conds = {}
conds['F'] = (df.gender == 'F')
conds['M'] = (df.gender == 'M')
conds['White F'] = (df.gender == 'F') & (df.race == 'White')

# plot for each condition
for key, value in conds.items():
    df.loc[value].groupby('year').rate.mean().plot(label=key, marker='o')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```